# SQLAlchemy introspect column type with inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, introspection

Considering this code (and using SQLAlchemy 0.7.7):

```
class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'document'
    __table_args__ = {
        'schema': 'app'
    }

    id = Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nom = Column(types.Unicode(256), nullable=False)
    date = Column(types.Date())

    type_document = Column(types.Enum('arrete', 'photographie',
        name='TYPES_DOCUMENT_ENUM'))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type_document}

class Arrete(Document):
    __tablename__ = 'arrete'
    __table_args__ = {
        'schema': 'app'
    }
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'arrete'}

    id = Column(types.Integer, ForeignKey('app.document.id'), primary_key=True)
    numero_arrete = Column(types.Integer)
    date_arrete = Column(types.Date())
```

I can easily introspect column type for column defined in `Arrete` class with:

```
Arrete.__table__.c['date_arrete'].type
```

But this doesn’t work if I want to access, through the `Arrete` class, a column defined in `Document` class. (KeyError if I try to access `c['date']`).

Is there a way to get column type, regardless if the column is defined in the final class or in one of its parent?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The ORM has allowed you to define classes in an inheritance pattern that corresponds to a JOIN of two tables.   This structure is full service, and can also be used to find out basic things like the types of attributes on columns, pretty much directly:

```
type = Arrete.date.property.columns[0].type
```

note that this is basically the same thing as the approach of trudging through `__bases__`, except you let Python's normal class mechanics do the work.

Comment: Huh, that's cleaner! Thanks! :)

Comment: @zzzeek is there a reason the `columns` attribute is a list? Are there situations where the first instance might not be the correct one?

Comment: same curiosity as @ricekab

Answer (score 7):

You can explore the base classes...

```
def find_type(class_, colname):
    if hasattr(class_, '__table__') and colname in class_.__table__.c:
        return class_.__table__.c[colname].type
    for base in class_.__bases__:
        return find_type(base, colname)
    raise NameError(colname)

print find_type(Arrete, 'date_arrete')
print find_type(Arrete, 'date')
```

Comment: I just add it as a @classmethod of my base class, and looks like to work just as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the problem with this answer is that it unnecessarily pokes through `__bases__`, when simply accessing `Arrete.date` will do that work for you.   SQLAlchemy of course can give you the column/datatype given a mapped attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [abstract special directive](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#abstract) or the [mixin pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes).

For a mixin, you'd use something like this:

```
class MyMixin(object):
    __tablename__ = 'document'
    __table_args__ = {
        'schema': 'app'
    }

    id = Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nom = Column(types.Unicode(256), nullable=False)
    date = Column(types.Date())

class Arrete(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'arrete'

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'arrete'}

    foreign_id = Column(types.Integer, ForeignKey('app.document.id'), primary_key=True)
    numero_arrete = Column(types.Integer)
    date_arrete = Column(types.Date())


class Document(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Document'
    type_document = Column(types.Enum('arrete', 'photographie',
        name='TYPES_DOCUMENT_ENUM'))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type_document}
```

Shared stuff goes in the mixin, non shared stuff in the sub classes.

Comment: Looks like it will break some other code of my app for which `Arrete` has to extend `Document`. I don’t want the exact syntax of my example to work (for getting the column type), but why I really want, if possible, is to keep the database unchanged.

Comment: @tonio If Arrete is just extending document, then there should only be one table, called `arrete`, on the db. You can't extend it the way you are wanting, because each `__table__` is an object, with a unique entry in the `metadata`. Trying to share the `__table__` object across classes prevents each class from having different tables. You may need to rethink your db model. Perhaps more details?

Comment: Arrete was here as an example, I got more table extending document. And several table with inheritance in my application that I don’t want to change. Maybe I should have better explained my needs, thanks for your help anyway.