# How to determine the expected type of SQLAlchemy column from an instance?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have an instance of a SQLAlchemy model and am trying to determine the types that the columns accept. Some of the columns attributes are None at the time I need to determine

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = Column(String())
```

Here is an pseudo code example of what I am trying to do.

```
user = User()
if type(inspect(user).get_property(id)) == Integer: 
   print "The id column expects Integers"
```

How do I turn this pseudo code into real code?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy introspect column type with inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632513/sqlalchemy-introspect-column-type-with-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(type(user).id.property.columns[0].type, Integer)
```